# Android widget OnReceive() being called multiple times when running WorkManager request

Tags: android, android-workmanager, glance-appwidget

I have an app which has a home screen widget via `GlanceAppWidget()`.

I would like to run a worker inside the `Content()` function of `GlanceAppWidget()`. I have used `enqueue(work)` from `WorkManager` api to successfully execute my worker.

The problem is that `onReceive` is getting called multiple (infinite) number of times. How can I run the worker once without having `onReceive` called multiple times?

```
class MyWidget : GlanceAppWidget() {

    @Composable
    override fun Content() {

        val work = OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorker::class.java).build()
        WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(work)

        //some composable/ui code that consumes worker output
    }
}
```

```
class MyWorker(
    private val context: Context,
    private val workerParameters: WorkerParameters
    ) : CoroutineWorker(context, workerParameters) {


    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
        return try {
            startForegroundService()
            //some task here
            Result.Success.success(
                workDataOf(
                    "MyKey" to "worker completed successfully"
                )
            )
        } catch (throwable: Throwable) {
            Result.failure()
        }
    }


    private suspend fun startForegroundService() {
        setForeground(
            ForegroundInfo(
                Random.nextInt(),
                NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "download_channel")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                    .setContentText("Downloading...")
                    .setContentTitle("Download in progress")
                    .build()
            )
        )
    }
}
```

```
class GlanceReceiver : GlanceAppWidgetReceiver() {

    override val glanceAppWidget: GlanceAppWidget
        get() = MyWidget()

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent)
    }

    override fun onUpdate(
        context: Context,
        appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager,
        appWidgetIds: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds)
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is onReceive called multiple times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72239911/why-is-onreceive-called-multiple-times)

Comment: Duplicated question. I answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/72282156/1695078